# Google+ public profile API limit

Tags: google-api, google-plus

We need to get user's profile picture from Google+ by API: https://content.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/{UID}?key={APP_KEY}(https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/get)

Does anyone know there is daily call limitation number or not ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Google+ API has two different quotas depending on the methods you call.

The "Sign-in" quota which includes the `people.get` method is limited to 20,000,000 calls per day (which should be plenty to get started). Even though it says "Sign-in" the methods will use this quota even if the calls are un-authenticated only using an API-Key.

You can visit the Quotas section in the Google APIs Console for your project to check these quotas (and how much you have used up already) and also request more if necessary:
https://code.google.com/apis/console/#:quotas

Also see the docs about which methods are included in the "sign-in" quota.
https://developers.google.com/+/api/#quota